# Using TCPDF to write text onto an image

Tags: php, tcpdf

I am brand new to the TCPDF library and after reading through the documentation I am not sure if it is possible to do what I need. I have an image file, lets call it background.tiff, and I want to place this image inside a new pdf and write some text ontop of this image in certain positions. I can't find any information or documentation on writing text onto an image, or even positioning text absolutely on the page. Is this something that should be done with writeHTML() instead? Ideally this pdf will be printed later - is it possible to 'outline' the text for printing purposes in TCPDF? Any help would be much appreciated, I am feeling a bit lost here.

edit: I am completely open to switching to another library if it would be a better solution.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried/experimented using [`Image()`](http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#a714c2bee7d6b39d4d6d304540c761352) and [`Write()`](http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#a6669ae88090963e9487d0388c7577dc9)/[`Cell()`](http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#a33b265e5eb3e4d1d4fedfe29f8166f31)/[`MultiCell()`](http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#aa81d4b585de305c054760ec983ed3ece)/[`writeHMTL()`](http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#ac3fdf25fcd36f1dce04f92187c621407)

Comment: @Sean I tried writeHTML with padding and absolute positioning but that didn't seem to work. I can't find any documentation on write(), can a position for text be set with it?

Comment: You can set the position first with [`SetXY()`](http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#a00ec13928f57b17c21040acc881fe482) and then use [`Write()`](http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#a6669ae88090963e9487d0388c7577dc9). Something like `$tcpdf->SetXY(50,120);$tcpdf->Write(10,'Write some text',...);` Note - if you click on any of the methods I mention, I have linked to the documentation. Once there you can search for any others.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Altough solution is already given in comment here's what u need to know:

1. [Image()](http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#a714c2bee7d6b39d4d6d304540c761352) - read about inserting an image into PDF document.
2. [SetX()](http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#a8d831d202e6420fe8fa6aeae7d3a2e8e), [SetY()](http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#ad3439990de56253b039bca6a09305758), [SetXY()](http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#a00ec13928f57b17c21040acc881fe482), [GetX()](http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#a415a80a301208fa77552048b27d2e0ce), [GetY()](http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#ae3b6169ba729309f289a5ac9680dd799) - read about setting/getting pointers. Keep in mind that PDF generation is pretty similar to printing process. If you generate some content, move pointer back over that content, and generate something new, it will appear on top of content u've 'printed' before.
3. Cell(), MultiCell(), Write() etc.

Oh, and if u want to be precise with generating PDFs try to avoid converting HTML to PDF. Use pointers instead. It's much more precise, works better with page breaks and u don't need to worry about CSS compatibility.